# Put information in label based on what user picked. c#

Tags: c#

I am currently trying to get a label(lets name it lblMessage) to pull information based on what the user has picked threw radio buttons and check boxes. Lets make the theme a sundae maker form.. people can select there flavor, size, and addons.

I'm just trying to make it so the label displays once they click the confirm button,  a message that identifies the number of sundaes, sundae flavor and size the person ordered. like.. (You ordered 2 small hot fudge sundaes which will cost you 
$x.xx (where x.xx is the cost for all sundaes ordered). I tried looking this up but i couldn't seem to find what to put into the label code... =\

I am a beginner at C# ... If any other information is needed, I can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is set the text of the label.  You can use the [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to take a string and replace certain values with values from variables, for example:

```
var result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Are you sure?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
{
    Decimal total = int.Parse(textBox1.Text) * 1.25m;

    // The {0} will be replaced with the first argument after the format string.
    // The total.ToString("C") tells the decimal to format the string into a currency string (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd(v=vs.110).aspx)
    label1.Text = String.Format("You ordered {0} small hot fudge sundaes, which will cost you {1}", textBox1.Text, total.ToString("C"));
}
```

Now this example still fails if the textbox does not contain an int, but that can easily be handled using the [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.